# Breaking Tie with Ward's Method Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: python, clustering, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, ward

Viewing the set of single-feature observations below, I think its obvious that the appropriate Euclidean distance-based (e.g., Ward's method) number of clusters is 3.

`s = [1, 2, 50, 51, 99, 100]`

But if we are forced to split `s` into only 2 clusters, then `50, 51` will get clustered with either `1, 2` or `99, 100` because:

`(2-50)**2 == (51-99)**2`

Should the 2-cluster assignment of `50, 51` in this scenario be considered random with every run, really just depending on the sequence of value comparisons? i.e., if a model's order of operations calculates the distance between `2` and `50` before it calculates the distance between `51` and `99`, then it will bucket it will bucket `50, 51` with `1, 2`?

The `AgglomerativeClustering` function from `sklearn.cluster` in Python3 show an interesting behavior. When the model is fit on `s`, in `s`'s original order, it always clusters `50, 51` with `1, 2`. But if we add randomness to the order of the `s` values, then `50, 51` always belong to the first cluster (Cluster 0), and its association with either `1, 2` or `99, 100` is completely random.

Below is the code that runs 10,000 trials of both scenarios. I've also printed the outcomes.

#### Import necessary packages and define the clustering algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering


# Define clustering algorithm
hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 2, 
                             affinity = 'euclidean', 
                             linkage ='ward')
```

#### Run 10,000 trials on `s`, retaining the order of `s` on every trial.

```
# Run 10,000 trials
for i in range(10000):
  s = [1,2,50,51,99,100]
  s = np.array(s).reshape(-1,1)
  
  # Fit clusters
  cluster_assignment = hc.fit_predict(s).tolist()

  df0 = pd.DataFrame({'value': s.flatten(), 
                      'cluster': cluster_assignment,
                      'run': i})
  
  #Append specific trial to total trials df
  try:
    df = pd.concat([df,df0], axis=0)
  except NameError:
    df = df0


results0 = df.groupby(['value', 'cluster']).run.count() \
  .reset_index()
del(df)

results = results0.pivot(index = 'value', columns = 'cluster')['run']
results.fillna(0)
```

[image]

#### Run 10,000 trials on `s`, but randomly shuffle the order of `s` on every trial.

```
import random

# Run 10,000 trials
for i in range(10000):
  s = [1,2,50,51,99,100]
  
  # Randomly shuffle the list
  random.shuffle(s)

  s = np.array(s).reshape(-1,1)
  
  # Fit clusters
  cluster_assignment = hc.fit_predict(s).tolist()
  df0 = pd.DataFrame({'value': s.flatten(), 
                      'cluster': cluster_assignment,
                      'run': i})
  
  #Append specific trial to total trials df
  try:
    df = pd.concat([df,df0], axis=0)
  except NameError:
    df = df0


results0 = df.groupby(['value', 'cluster']).run.count() \
  .reset_index()
del(df)

results = results0.pivot(index = 'value', columns = 'cluster')['run']
results.fillna(0)
```

[image]

Comment: The input dustance matrix between your 6 objects contains many ties. The minimal distance (=1) ia so tied (encounters two times). So what is your wonder or your question?

Comment: @ttnphns - correct, and the tie that I'm concerned with in this example is when we aggregate the clusters from 3 clusters to 2. Should the algorithm randomly decide if `50, 51` get clustered with either `1, 2` or `99, 100`, potentially returning different results depending on the run? You are right though, the same question would apply if trying to assess clusters at cluster sizes 5 and 4 too, because of the three equidistance-pairs that we're starting with.

Comment: When there are ties, random selection among them (which to process) is no way better than a deterministic selection (such as, pick, among the ties, the distance with the least or the greatest ordinal index in the matrix). At least, it is how it is with clustering. There is no good or universal solution of the problem of ties.

Comment: Sometimes in the presence of some amout of ties in the input matrix distance an investigator would like to see if the ties affect the final cluster solution (of say, k clusters). In other words, if the solution is stable (robust) against the ties. Then he/she would repeat the analysis a number of times with different order of items (rows/columns in the matrix) and compare the results.